# ESP8266 CIPSEND GET HTTP Host Request Time-out

Tags: http, arduino, request, timeout, esp8266

```
AT+CIPSEND=65


OK
> 
Recv 65 bytes

SEND OK

+IPD,394:HTTP/1.1 408 Request Time-out
Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2016 05:24:40 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 223
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>408 Request Time-out</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request Time-out</h1>
<p>Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client.</p>
</body></html>
CLOSED
```

I always get 408 request timeout
the link is working
the length is okay

tx is to rx
rx is to tx

i have search the google many times.
still haven't have the solution
i also tried different link.

I am using Arduino Mega 2560 and esp8266 or esp-01

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I Have The Solution

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/23319/esp8266-sending-get-request-and-getting-408-timeout-error/23342#23342

I assume you're doing all this from the serial monitor. You can't use escape sequences like \r in the serial monitor entry box. Everything you enter is evaluated as a string of separate ASCII characters; \r is just a backslash character followed by lowercase r. To send a HTTP request, you make the serial monitor send the \r\n for you.

- First set the serial monitor to BOTH NL & CR permanently; it will serve you well for commands and HTTP requests as it appends \r\n to everything you send.
- Count the number of bytes in the your HTTP request, including the carriage return and newline characters. I count 61 characters in your request.
- Use this count in AT+CIPSEND
- the first line of your request, and stop right before the first \r\n, and click Send. Because of your setting, the monitor will now send what you typed with \r\n suffixed to it.
- Type and send each line of the request, just like you sent the first line, until you've sent the last line.
- Since there is an additional \r\n after the last line, you click Send again, without typing anything. And since the module requires \r to indicate the end of the data packet, you click Send one last time.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13445629)

Comment: Sorry for that.
i have made changes to the answer with engough content that answers my question :)